# How do we change WSO2 API logo for public and store URLs?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I am trying to customize wso2am-2.0.0 server logo & themes in all server URLs like carbon,public and store. How to do that?

Moreover am not able to view theme settings from admin console.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change logo for this

https://localhost:9443/store/

you can do by going to this path

wso2am-2.0.0\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\store\site\themes\wso2\libs\theme-wso2_1.0\images and change the file logo-inverse.svg

Comment: Indent the code properly and add more description regarding your answer.

Comment: This was helpful! wso2am-2.0.0\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\store\site\themes\wso2\libs\theme-wso2_1.0\images and change the file logo-inverse.svg

Answer (score 0):

Customizing each component requires different set of steps.

1. Customizing Carbon theme - You can use [[1]](http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/11/playing-around-carbon-product-themes/) with changes to following bundles org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.4.7.jar, org.wso2.am.styles_2.0.0.jar respectively in place of org.wso2.carbon.ui-3.2.2.jar and org.wso2.esb.styles-3.2.0.jar.
2. Customizing store - This you can achieve by using [[2]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+a+New+API+Store+Theme) which provides a step by step guide to change the current theme in WSO2 Api Manager Store theme.
3. Customizing Publisher - Following the same method in customizing store you can do the same changes to theme files in /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/themes.

follow the steps in Saving directly in the file system since for publisher

[1](http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/11/playing-around-carbon-product-themes/) http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/11/playing-around-carbon-product-themes/

[2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+a+New+API+Store+Theme) https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+a+New+API+Store+Theme